# MySQL select unique records from one table with two select queries using NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

| TaskNumber | JobNumber | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | JS0001 | 0 | 04-06-2021 |
| 11112 | JS0002 | 0 | 05-06-2021 |
| 11113 | JS0003 | 1 | 05-06-2021 |
| 11114 | JS0001 | 1 | 06-06-2021 |

**Table Tasks.
TaskNumber is the unique id(primary key).
Status 0 is not done, 1 is done.**

example:
JobNumber JS0001 assigned on 04th of june and not done,
so reassigned on 06th of june and was completed(status 1)

How do i get the unique job numbers that are not done using mysql query?
(Only the Jobnumbers that are not completed for example JS0002 and not JS0001 on 04-06-2021)?

I have tried following statement but it just shows all records where status is 0, is it possible to write two select statements and compare using NOT IN?

*SELECT DISTINCT Job_no FROM TASKS WHERE status='0'*

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use aggregation and `having`:

```
select jobnumber
from tasks
group by jobnumber
having max(status) = 0;
```

Comment: this answer works well, also how do i count all these records,
I tried using

_select count(*) from Tasks having max(status) = '0'_

but returns 0

Comment: @iwhd . . . You can use this as a subquery:  `select count(*) from ( . . . ) t`.